# Why can't I run this executable file (.exe) in Octave?

Tags: executable, execute-command, octave, fortran

I have a source code written in Fortran 90: sourcecode.f90

It needs Lapack libraries for compilation so, I compile the source code with this command:

```
gfortran -o executable.exe sourcecode.f90 -llapack
```

When I run this executable file in Ubuntu terminal using:

```
./executable.exe
```

everything runs fine. But when I try to run the same executable file in an Octave script with the line:

```
system("./executable.exe")
```

I get this error in the Octave command window:

```
./executable.exe: error while loading shared libraries: liblapack.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone help me understand why this is happening? I need to run executable.exe in Octave for a larger code, but because of this, I'm unable to do so.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with Octave 5.2.0.

Comment: Was Octave 5.2.0 installed as a snap?

Comment: I installed Octave through flatpak. Does this make a difference? Because in another earlier system, I'd installed Octave through the gui software store, and it would run system('./executable.exe') just fine.

Comment: TBH I don't know much about containerisation  but I suspect it might (i.e. not allowing access to shared libs outside of the container). There *might* be a workaround by copying the required libraries to somewhere in your home area and using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to make the linker search there (containers usually allow access to user's home)

Answer (score 0):

type the below commands

```
system('echo $SHELL');
system('echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH');
```

and see if they look the same as typing echo in your Ubuntu terminals, if they are not the same, likely you started your octave from a launcher, which starts a non-interactive shell instead of an interactive shell (these cases, they have different rc files, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/170499/366890). you can at least run

```
system('LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/liblapack.so/folder ./executable.exe')
```

alternatively, find the correct rc file and add the path to `LD_LIBRARYPATH` in that environment.

Comment: In Ubuntu terminal, I typed `echo $SHELL` and got `/bin/bash` as output. I typed `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and got no output. I got the same results when I ran them in Octave comand window using `system ('echo $SHELL')` and `system('echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH')`. When I typed `whereis liblapack.so` in Ubuntu terminal, I got `liblapack: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblapack.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblapack.a`. So in the Octave command window, I ran `system ("LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ ./executable.exe")` but got the same error message.

Comment: When I run `octave` in Ubuntu terminal, it says `Command 'octave' not found` even though I've installed octave through flatpak and can start the Octave gui from the applications launcher on the dock. Does this have anything to do with the present problem?

Comment: I tried adding the location of octave-gui and adding `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in .bashrc in home folder, and in /etc/bash.bashrc with sudo privileges. These didn't help either. I then uninstalled octave and flatpak and reinstalled octave using `sudo apt-get intall octave`. Although the version I now have is older than earlier, the `system("./executable.exe")` command is now running fine without issues. Thanks for the help.